# How to use more than one style attribute in HTML

Tags: html

```
<p style="color:red;"> text here </p>th
```

This code works however how would I make the text bigger as well since that uses the style attribute?

Comment: why don't you just make a CSS class that does red and big then assign it to that paragraph tag?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The way to do this directly in your HTML is this:

```
<p style="color: red; font-size: 50px;"> text here </p>
```

As you can see, you simply separate the style rules with the semicolon.

However, if you want to do this using CSS, you could do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<p class="large-red-text">text here</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.large-red-text {
    color: red;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

Just be sure to save your CSS in a file with the `.css` extension and include it in your HTML in the `<head>` tag like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="filename.css" />
```

Comment: A correction to the above. You need a ; after the 50px. (i.e., style="color: red; font-size: 50px;">). At least mine did not work until I made this change.

Comment: @Glyn I've updated my answer with this change. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Basically you have three options how to implement CSS:

1. INLINE STYLES

You put CSS right into HTML element. Multiple CSS attributes are divided by semicolon `;` e.g. `<p style="color:red; margin: 0;">`

2. USING `<style>` TAG

You put your CSS into `<style>` tag in your HTML (`.html`) file:

```
<style>
p {
   color: red;
   margin: 0;
}
</style>
```

3. CSS IN EXTERNAL .CSS FILE

You put your CSS into separated file with `.css` suffix and then include that file in `<head>` tag in your HTML file: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path">`

Comment: You should provide some explanation for the code you posted.

Comment: Could you provide some explanation? Thank you